# How can I get IFTTT to print the <br> tag in a text file instead of using it for a new line?

Tags: dropbox, if-this-then-that

I have a recipe that drops the weather forecast for the day into a text file in dropbox. It's set up to insert the report as html within `<div>` blocks so that it formats nicely when rendering Markdown. It all works fine except for the `<br>` tags. I want them to print in the text file as `<br>` but instead they are printed as new lines. Obviously, this is what is expected, but is there a way around it?

I can enter `<br><br>` and get the line breaks in Markdown, but because they're between 2 `<div>` tags, Markdown renders them as html and ignores the line breaks.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the brackets? Maybe it can do the trick `\<br\>`

Comment: did you tried </br> ?

Comment: I tried `<br />` but it converted it to `<br>`. I can try the other formats and see what happens.

Comment: Try encoding them: `&lt;br&gt;`

Comment: I tried `\<br\>` and `&lt;br&gt;` and IFTTT converted them both to `<br>`. I also tried `</br>` but IFTTT deleted it.